# AsyncTask not starting after device rotate even after object re-creation

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a REST server that spits out data from a remote ADC, and I need to graph the data just for presentation. I used AsyncTask to move the data aquisition off of the main thread to prevent `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. I wrote this:

```
package inostiot.inostiot;

// imports

public class MonitorActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private GraphWorker worker;

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        worker.cancel(true);
        outState.putBundle("state", worker.prepareResume());
        outState.putBoolean("resuming", true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_monitor);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        String ip = extras.getString("ip");

        LineChart chart = (LineChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);

        XAxis x = chart.getXAxis();
        YAxis y = chart.getAxisLeft();

        // More chart setup here, ignore

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {

            boolean resuming = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("resuming", false);

            if (resuming) {
                worker = new GraphWorker(this, ip, chart, true);
                worker.resume(savedInstanceState.getBundle("state"));
                worker.execute();
            }

        } else {
            worker = new GraphWorker(this, ip, chart, false);
            worker.execute();
        }
    }
}


class GraphWorker extends AsyncTask<Void, Object, Void> {

    private LineChart chart;
    private boolean resuming;
    private boolean running = true;
    private String ip;
    private Activity parent;

    private ArrayList<ADCPort> ports;
    private ArrayList<WalkingDataset> walkingDatasets;
    private ArrayList<LineDataSet> lineDataSets;

    GraphWorker(Activity parent, String ip, LineChart chart, boolean resuming) {

        this.parent = parent;

        if (!resuming) {
            ports = new ArrayList<>();
            walkingDatasets  = new ArrayList<>();
            this.ip = ip;
        }

        this.chart = chart;
        this.resuming = resuming;
        lineDataSets = new ArrayList<>();


    }

    @Override
    public Void doInBackground(Void...params) {

        ADC adc = new ADC(ip);

        if (!resuming) {

            if (!adc.auth()) throw new RuntimeException("Server invalid!");

            ports.add(new ColoredADCPort(0, "#FF0000"));
            walkingDatasets.add(new WalkingDataset(10));

            // More ports are initialized here, just copy-paste an
            // color change


        }


        while (running) {

            try {

                ports = adc.readPorts(ports);
                publishProgress((Object)ports);

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } catch (ADCException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
            }

        }

        return null;

    }

    void resume(Bundle data) {
        this.ports = (ArrayList<ADCPort>) data.getSerializable("ports");
        this.walkingDatasets = (ArrayList<WalkingDataset>) data.getSerializable("walkingDatasets");
        this.ip = data.getString("ip");
        this.chart.invalidate();
    }

    Bundle prepareResume() {
        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        data.putSerializable("ports", ports);
        data.putSerializable("walkingDatasets", walkingDatasets);
        data.putString("ip", ip);
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Object... values) {

        ArrayList<ADCPort> ports = (ArrayList<ADCPort>) values[0];

        lineDataSets.clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < ports.size(); i++) {

            ColoredADCPort port = (ColoredADCPort) ports.get(i);
            WalkingDataset dataset = walkingDatasets.get(i);

            dataset.add(port.getValue());

            LineDataSet lineDataSet = new LineDataSet(dataset, String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "Sensor %d", i));
            lineDataSet.setCircleColor(Color.parseColor(port.getColor()));
            lineDataSet.setColor(Color.parseColor(port.getColor()));
            lineDataSet.setDrawValues(false);

            lineDataSets.add(lineDataSet);

        }

        final LineData data = new LineData();

        for (LineDataSet set : lineDataSets) {
            data.addDataSet(set);
        }

        chart.setData(data);
        chart.postInvalidate();

        super.onProgressUpdate();
    }

    public void stopRunner() {
        this.running = false;
    }

}
```

There is a `LineChart` from `MPAndroidCharts` on the Activity, and the AsyncTask is supposed to update the UI with the new chart data that it gets from the server. However, after a device rotation and after the `resume()` method of `GraphWorker` is called to restore the object state, and after calling `execute()`, `doInBackground()` is never called or being run. Why?

Answer (score 0):

I need to stop the previous worker before starting another.

In sequential processing all Async tasks run in a single thread and thus have to wait before the previous task ends. If you need to execute code immediately, you need tasks to be processed in parallel in separate threads.

So, adding `running=false` in `prepareResume` to stop the previous worker solves this issue.